# Sending Image to server takes lot of time

Tags: php, android, image

In my android application i am trying to send captured image from camera to my php server .
Sometime image is successfully send to the server or sometime it failed send to the server.I think Image is not send to server because it take lot time. So How could i solve this issue please guide me.i am attached full source code here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    InputStream is;
    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo,upload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
        upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(bitmap==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    new ImageUpload().execute();
                }

            }
        });

        /*
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        /*
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /*
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /*
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                            // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
     * */

    /*
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please Wait Image is Uploading");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

            String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,1);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

            try
            {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.86/camera/upload.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

            //Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Joining Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Successfully Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }



    }
}
```

Here is manifest file
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog pd;
InputStream is;
// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView videoPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo,upload;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
    upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(bitmap==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                new ImageUpload().execute();
            }

        }
    });

    /*
     * Capture image button click event
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    /*
     * Record video button click event
     */
    btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // record video
            recordVideo();
        }
    });

    // Checking camera availability
    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/*
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/*
 * Recording video
 */
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // video successfully recorded
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // hide video preview
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Previewing recorded video
 */
private void previewVideo() {
    try {
        // hide image preview
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
        // start playing
        videoPreview.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
 * */

/*
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/*
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait Image is Uploading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,1);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

        try
        {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.86/camera/upload.php");

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

        //Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Joining Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Successfully Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pd.dismiss();
    }



}
```

}
here is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.androidcameraapi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.androidcameraapi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here Is ServeSide Code

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';?>
```

Comment: Send image to server using multipart.

Comment: You can reduce image size by scaledown `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use

> HttpURLConnection

to upload, just as an example have a look on the following code and try and modify accordingly.

[Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106